# When does differentiability of $g\circ f$ and $f$ resp. $g$ imply differentiablity of $g$ resp. $f$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, banach-spaces, function-and-relation-composition

To me the following seems intuitively true:

- If $f$ is differentiable at $x$ with surjective derivative then $g$ is differentiable at $f(x)$ iff $g\circ f$ is differentiable at $x$.
- On the other hand, if $g$ is differentiable at $f(x)$ with injective derivative then $f$ is differentiable at $x$ iff $g\circ f$ is differentiable at $x$.

I assume $f,g$ to be mappings between Banach spaces but I guess this should not make a huge difference.

Comment: Is there a question you want to ask?

Comment: Yes, if my conditions are enough or if there are stronger conditions needed to make this work.

Comment: Pretty sure it has something to do with the inverse function theorem, unfortunately I haven't really worked through this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Useful fact 1**: If $f$ is differentiable at $x$ with surjective derivative, then there is an open neighborhood $U$ containing $f(x)$ and a map $s$ on $U$ such that $f\circ s=id_U$.

**Useful fact 2**: If $g$ is differentiable at $y$ with injective derivative, then there is an open neighborhood $V$ containing $g(y)$ and a map $p$ on $V$ such that $p\circ g=id$.

These facts can be shown by the inverse function theorem.

We now show that the first condition holds. One direction is clear. Assume $g\circ f$ is differentiable at $x$, and let $s$ as in useful fact 1. Then locally we have$$g=g\circ id=g\circ (f\circ s)=(g\circ f)\circ s$$and hence $g$ is differentiable as a composition of differentiable maps.

The second condition can be proved similarly, using fact 2.

Comment: Does this also hold for Banach spaces?  I thought about the case $g\circ f$ is differentiable and $f$ is continuous, surjective and linear.  As far as I can see, any (not necessarily continuous) linear right inverse $s$ of $f$ satisfies ${\rm img}(s)$ is a complement of ${\rm ker}(g)$.  Further I think $s$ is continuous if and only if ${\rm img}(s)$ is closed.  But there are Banach spaces $E$ with a closed subspace $F$ that is not complemented, i.e. no there exists no closed complement of $F$, so the continuous map $\pi:E\rightarrow E/F$ should have no continuous linear right inverse, right?

Comment: OK, this was a little bit off topic maybe...  Anyway, thanks a lot for the well-versed answer!